# Can I pause / stop ExoPlayer from a different Activity / Fragment even though I initialize it in my Adapter class?

Tags: java, android

So what I would like to know is if I have written the code for the `ExoPlayer` and `PlayerView` in my `Adapter` class, because I need the holder because I have multiple view types (images and videos), and so I was wondering is it possible to pause it and resume it from another Activity or Fragment, or do I have to do it directly in the Adapter class?

What I need is for the Player to pause automatically when the user navigates away from the screen to another `Activity / Fragment` if the ExoPlayer is in the middle of playing a video, or when they close the app entirely.

What options do I have?

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        PlayerView mPlayerView;
        SimpleExoPlayer mExoPlayer;

        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

           mPlayerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exo_player);
            mRelativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_one);

            mLocation.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MapsActivityUser.class);
                intent.putExtra("postid", mPostList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPostid());
                intent.putExtra("text_event", mPostList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getText_event());
                intent.putExtra("text_location", mPostList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getText_location());
                intent.putExtra("text_date_time", mPostList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getText_date_time());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            });
        }

        public void setVideo(String videoUrl) {

            try {
                BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder(mContext).build();
                TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
                mExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(mContext, trackSelector);
                Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
                DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("posts");
                ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
                MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
                mPlayerView.setPlayer(mExoPlayer);
                mExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
                mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ViewHolder", "ExoPlayer error: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put your ExoPlayer in a [service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service) so you can do any actions on it from anywhere.

If you wanna your service to stick, return [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#START_STICKY) on [onStartCommand](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int))

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your response. I am going to look into this because I am super stuck with this. You have any good practical examples of how to make this work with the ExoPlayer? Should I create a separate Activity with the ExoPlayer for this to work, or interface?

Comment: No. No extras activities needed. Just start the service and initialize the ExoPlayer ^^. Please, read the content of this link (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services). It will help you a lot.

Comment: Okay man, I'm going to try it out I'll let you know if it works...